# Inserting Weekday into table from Date field mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, date

I have an HTML5 form that takes in the date which is then submit to my MySQL via PHP. On my display results page I show the date, as well as the Weekday using `DATE_FORMAT`. Everything works fine when displaying date and weekday. I also have a search feature that looks through the database for the terms entered.

The problem is, the weekday isn't stored in the database. Only the date is stored. So if a user searches for "Monday" nothing will show up.  I can't really figure out how to insert weekday into my `INSERT` statement either since I don't actually have a field in my HTML5 form for weekday.

If you understand my predicament, can you assist me? I basically need to insert the current weekday into it's own column in my table WITHOUT having the user doing any extra work.

I can provide code samples if necessary.

Comment: You should always include code samples - this should be easily done in the php used to insert the values to mysql.  What does php code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hidden field with that information in it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="weekday" value="Tuesday" />
```

Then when it gets submitted, it will be saved without the user having to do anything.

You can get the weekday from your original date string by using php strtotime and date functions.

Comment: What would I put in the value to automatically change the weekday?

Comment: Ok have to figure out how to get strtotime. Never used it before.

Comment: you would put a php function with your original date - <?php date('l',strtotime('2012-11-16')) ?> that's a lower case 'L' in the date function, it returns a full length weekday from any given time retrieved from strtotime

Comment: strtotime is pretty easy, as long as you provide it with a reasonably common date format, it will give you the 'seconds since the epoch' that php requires to do time calculations. You can even subtract or add to/from your dates, like '2012-11-16 -1 week' should give you one week before the Nov 16th, 2012. It is very useful.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks! This is what I put just in case anyone was wondering.

`<input type="hidden" name="weekday" value="<?php echo date('l',strtotime('now')); ?>">`